# Fill an SVG shape with a gradient

Tags: css, svg, linear-gradients

[image: Wavy shape with gradient]

[image: wavy shape]

[image: linear gradient]

How can I apply Linear gradient and drop shadow to this pattern?

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 60 10">
  <pattern x="-8" id="waves" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="10" height="10">
    <path d="M0 10 V5 Q2.5 3.5 5 5 T10 5 V10" fill="#FFC338" />
  </pattern>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="60" height="7" fill="url(#waves)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: What would it look like if you had a gradient and a pattern?

Comment: gradient like in the image above and pattern same as u run the above code

Comment: That's just a gradient. Where's the pattern.

Comment: pattern u can see by running the code

Comment: pattern is above now

Comment: And we're back to my first question, what do they look like if you put them together?

Comment: it is looking like this but i need that the same gradient as shown in the lower portion in the above part

Comment: You would need to turn your patterned (wavy) rectangle into a mask. Then apply that to another rectangle that has the gradient fill.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As commented by [Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328302/how-can-i-use-the-linear-gradient-to-this-yellow-path-and-how-to-apply-shadow-t#comment62199058_37328302), you need to convert the wavy shape to one path, then you can fill the wavy shape with a [linear gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/linearGradient) as shown in this example:

```html
<svg viewbox="7.5 0 60 10">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient">
      <stop offset="5%" stop-color="#FFC338" />
      <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#FFEA68" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <path fill="url(#gradient)" d="M0 10 V5 Q2.5 2.5 5 5 t5 0 t5 0 t5 0 t5 0 t5 0 t5 0 t5 0 t5 0 t5 0 t5 0 t5 0 t5 0 t5 0 t5 0 V10" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Does anybody know why they always use in examples 5% and 95% instead of 0% and 100%?
Just curious...

Comment: @noitseuq no real reason it doesn't make much difference in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Place all the gradient and pattern definitions within a `<defs>` block.
After the defs block is closed place your visible content tags.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you are looking for, but try this. Edit numerical parameters individually to see the effect.

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 80">
   <defs>
     <filter id="f1" x="0" y="0" width="140%" height="200%">
       <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceAlpha" dx="8" dy="6" />
       <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="offOut" stdDeviation="10" />
       <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal" />
     </filter>

    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,0);stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1" />
    </linearGradient>

      <pattern x="-8" id="waves" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="50" height="20">
        <path d="M0 10 V5 Q2.5 3.5 5 5 T10 5 V10" fill="url(#grad1)" />
      </pattern>
   </defs>

   <rect x="0" y="3" width="200" height="20"  fill="url(#waves)"  filter="url(#f1)" />
</svg>
```