# Changing <svg> and <path> elements background color

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm currently uninstalling a page builder on my website,
 but I want to keep some of its styles.

I copied the html of an element, it used to have a red color on the stripes which are now black/grey, but I got problems changing the color of them.

Only color I can change is the `background`.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="max-height:100px;
        margin-bottom: 30px;" viewBox="0 0 1000 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path style="width: 2500px;" opacity="0.33" d="M473,67.3c-203.9,88.3-263.1-34-320.3,0C66,119.1,0,59.7,0,59.7V0h1000v59.7 c0,0-62.1,26.1-94.9,29.3c-32.8,3.3-62.8-12.3-75.8-22.1C806,49.6,745.3,8.7,694.9,4.7S492.4,59,473,67.3z"></path>
    <path style="width: 2500px;" opacity="0.66" d="M734,67.3c-45.5,0-77.2-23.2-129.1-39.1c-28.6-8.7-150.3-10.1-254,39.1 s-91.7-34.4-149.2,0C115.7,118.3,0,39.8,0,39.8V0h1000v36.5c0,0-28.2-18.5-92.1-18.5C810.2,18.1,775.7,67.3,734,67.3z"></path>
    <path style="width: 2500px;" d="M766.1,28.9c-200-57.5-266,65.5-395.1,19.5C242,1.8,242,5.4,184.8,20.6C128,35.8,132.3,44.9,89.9,52.5C28.6,63.7,0,0,0,0 h1000c0,0-9.9,40.9-83.6,48.1S829.6,47,766.1,28.9z"></path>
</svg>
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Comment: [SVG TUTORIAL](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_intro.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probabily want to include the css files from your page builder to add the style to your HTML page.

But for now, if you want your `<svg>` to be red use the property `fill`:

```css
path {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="max-height:100px;
        margin-bottom: 30px;" viewBox="0 0 1000 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path style="width: 2500px;" opacity="0.33" d="M473,67.3c-203.9,88.3-263.1-34-320.3,0C66,119.1,0,59.7,0,59.7V0h1000v59.7 c0,0-62.1,26.1-94.9,29.3c-32.8,3.3-62.8-12.3-75.8-22.1C806,49.6,745.3,8.7,694.9,4.7S492.4,59,473,67.3z"></path>
    <path style="width: 2500px;" opacity="0.66" d="M734,67.3c-45.5,0-77.2-23.2-129.1-39.1c-28.6-8.7-150.3-10.1-254,39.1 s-91.7-34.4-149.2,0C115.7,118.3,0,39.8,0,39.8V0h1000v36.5c0,0-28.2-18.5-92.1-18.5C810.2,18.1,775.7,67.3,734,67.3z"></path>
    <path style="width: 2500px;" d="M766.1,28.9c-200-57.5-266,65.5-395.1,19.5C242,1.8,242,5.4,184.8,20.6C128,35.8,132.3,44.9,89.9,52.5C28.6,63.7,0,0,0,0 h1000c0,0-9.9,40.9-83.6,48.1S829.6,47,766.1,28.9z"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: dont know why this was downvoted, thank you so much!

Comment: Do you know if you can add a gradient to a fill style?

Comment: @TimvonKänel Check how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328302)